# How to handle conflicting Visual State Setters in separate Visual State Groups?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Let's say I've got a RadioButton style defined in a XAML ResourceDictionary (no code-behind):

```
<Style x:Key="ExampleRadioButtonStyle"
       TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    ???
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Fill" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Stroke" Value="Blue" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Stroke" Value="Black" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Content" 
                             StrokeThickness="5"/>
                </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now I want to change the **Content**.Stroke property when the **CommonStates**.CurrentState is *PointerOver* to:

- *Cyan* when the **CheckStates**.CurrentState is *Checked*
- *Gray* when the **CheckStates**.CurrentState is *Unchecked*

What is the best way to achieve that?

Please note that this is just a simplified example prepared to present my problem which is much more complex in reality (for example I need to handle all CommonStates) so I look for a decent solution not a simple workaround handling only the mouse over behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you provided, we can't directly get the selected state of the RadioButton from PointerOver.You can follow the native style,create two Ellipse,one for the selected state and the other for the unselected.Use the Check status switch to show or hideEllipse.Then set the stroke in PointerOver.For example:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="Content" Fill="{StaticResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFill}" Height="20" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="CheckedContent" Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFill}" Height="20" Opacity="0" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
```

When the CheckStates.CurrentState is Checked,you can show the CheckedContent and hide Content,the UnChecked the opposite.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
        <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter Target="Content.Opacity" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Fill" Value="White" />
            <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Stroke" Value="Blue" />
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
    ......                                    
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Then you can set stroke for different states in PointerOver.

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <VisualState.Setters>​
        <Setter Target="Content.Stroke" Value="Gray"></Setter>​
        <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Stroke" Value="Cyan"></Setter>​
    </VisualState.Setters>​
</VisualState>
```

Comment: nice way out. Thought about this question and haven't found and answer, waited for you to reply :)